# Jackson does not include type info for fields while serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to serialize an object to json using jackson 2.6.3
I want to include type info in the serialized json. This does not work for members nested within this class.

Here is the test code.

```
public class Test {

@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteA.class)})
interface A {

}
@JsonTypeInfo( use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
class ConcreteA implements A {

}

@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteB.class)})
interface B {

}
@JsonTypeInfo( use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
class ConcreteB implements B {
    A a;
    public A getA() {
        return a=new ConcreteA();
    }
}

@org.junit.Test
public void testSerialisation() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new ConcreteB()));
}
}
```

The json being converted by jackson is

```
{"@class":"Test$ConcreteB","a":{}}
```

Note that it does not include type info for field 'a'. The type info does get included while serializing just A.

```
{"@class":"Test$ConcreteA"}
```

UPDATE:
Here is the explanation and solution from jackson dev for the problem
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1015

Comment: Why would you need the type info for 'a' when serializing B? When you deserialize to 'B' the type of 'a' will be given by B.

Comment: A is an interface and can have many implementations. How do you know which type to deserialize without the type information?

Comment: I see the problem now, also got it working.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you were pretty close, all you need to add is a way to tell jackson how to handle your interface type.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "@class")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteA.class)})
interface A {
}
```

So adding the `@JsonTypeInfo` to your interface will add the type information in a property you can configure to be the one you expect, in this case I chose `@class`.

The Json output I got from my example:

`{"@class":"com.company.jackson.Test$ConcreteB","a":{"@type":"Test$ConcreteA"}}`

Hope it helps,

José Luis

Comment: adding just @JsonTypeInfo( use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS) to A works.
Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked and helped you,  would you please accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to have fully qualified class name in "@class". Above solution puts the type name in "@class". Using JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS instead puts the class name of the interface not the implementation.

Comment: When we apply it in arrays, Jackson doesn't apply "@class" to the generated JSON. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

You also have to set the **visible** property to true, otherwise it might still not work(my case). I will enhance one of the above answers:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "@class",
        visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ConcreteA.class)})
interface A {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.
I had imported wrong ObjectMapper class.

Ideally, it should be **jackson-databind.jar**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
```

but I have imported **jackson-mapper-asl.jar**

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
```